# Сохранение данных в EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Есть модель в проекте

```
public class Repositories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfChange { get; set; }
}
```

Есть цикл который заполняет 2 переменные fileName и i

```
foreach (IndexEntry e in repo.Index)
{
    var fileName = "";
    var i = 0;
    fileName = e.Path;

    foreach (var commit in repo.Commits)
    {
        foreach (var parent in commit.Parents)
        {
            foreach (var change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree))
            {
                if (change.Path == fileName)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    _context.UpdateRange(fileName, i);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Как добавить записи в таблицу из этого цикла(fileName=Name, NumberOfChange=i)?

Comment: `_context.Repositories.Add(new Repositories { Name  = "asdf", NumberOfChange = 123 });`?

Comment: у вас есть контекст. есть поля контекста, у них них есть метод `Add` - какие проблемы с его вызовом?

Comment: @AK, спасибо, выручаете)

Comment: Допишите до ответа - и опубликуйте, вдруг кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task CounterChangeFileInLocalrepositiry()
{

    var repo = new Repository(RepoPath);


    foreach (IndexEntry e in repo.Index)
    {
        var fileName = "";
        var i = 0;
        fileName = e.Path;

        foreach (var commit in repo.Commits)
        {
            foreach (var parent in commit.Parents)
            {
                foreach (var change in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(parent.Tree, commit.Tree))
                {
                    if (change.Path == fileName)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //TODO Check
        _context.Repositoryes.Add(new Repositories { Name = fileName, NumberOfChange = i });
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
}
```